# installation of Kubuntu 15.10 finished but booting to grub rescue

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

I did installation of kUbuntu 15.10 but on restart booted to grub rescue. I tried grub repair by live boot, but it is asking me to make efi partition. Wasnt efi should be made during installation?

same thing happened with Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 3):

The installation you created was made as an EFI installation. The system created an EFI partition on your system but during the boot the system sees that you are not using an EFI boot. And it then falls into a grub rescue. A screen like this...

[image]

2 things I tried:

- boot repair did not help. It will complain about you trying to repair a GPT/EFI system on a grub-pc (non-efi) system.
- The normal update-grub did also not work.

I fixed this by going into BIOS, creating an "Ubuntu EFI" boot option, pointing it to the EFI file on the installer DVD and boot from there and re-install Ubuntu.

Mind that my problem was even weirder: I used an UPGRADE from a NON-efi Ubuntu 15.04 and the system created an EFI based Ubuntu 15.10. It even made a EFI partition (saw that when I got to the partitioning part of my re-install).

I myself consider this a critical issue: I had lots of trouble getting my system back up and running and do not consider myself a new Ubuntu user. Someone else might make the mistake of formatting personal data.

Comment: actually I tried installation 3 times but failed :-/  but 4th time I formatted the whole hard drive and did the installation, it was successful. but lost many files